# vectors and cartesian equation on the line in 3d

Tags: vector-spaces

Find in scalar parametric form an equation for the line of intersection of the plane $P$ and the plane with Cartesian equation $2x + y − z = 0$. $P= x − 2y + z = 1$.

Comment: Consider $\mathbf{x}=(x,y,z)$ and the planes $\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{x}=d_1, \mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{x}=d_1$. Then $[\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b}]$ (the cross product) points along the line. Also you have to find a point in planes' intersection. Sorry, manually, by solving equations.

Comment: does that mean x=(2,1,-1)?. do i find the d1 and then a and b, therefore cross product both of them for the answer?

Comment: Sorry, a typo with d_1 and d_2. I meant a=(2,1,-1) and b=(1,-2,1).

Comment: when i do find the intersection what do i do next?

Comment: Then the line equation if simply written down in the form $\frac{x-x_0}{-1}=\frac{y-y_0}{-3}=\frac{z-z_0}{-5}$ where $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is the point and $(-1,-3,-5)$ is the cross product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving:

$$
\begin {cases}
2x+y-z=0\\
x-2y+z=1
\end {cases}
$$
we have:
$$
\begin {cases}
y=3x-1\\
z=5x-1
\end {cases}
$$
so, for $x=t$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
-1\\
-1
\end{bmatrix} +t
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
3\\
5
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 2):

You can use $z$ as a parameter and solve the system of two equations. This will give you a parametric definition of the intersection line.